# Multiple variables javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, dictionary, leaflet

I want to add multiple attributes to my map but only one at a time works:

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}, {dragging: false})
```

This doesn't work. I don't know Javascript, so it's probably just a syntax error.

Comment: Is this Leaflet ? You should add a keywords to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`L.map()`'s second argument is an object. You supply three, so it's not picking up the third. Consolidate your object by lumping the second and third arguments together into one object:

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false, dragging: false})
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be one object with multiple keys/values:

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false, dragging: false})
```